# Parsing JSON in React Native fetch method doesnt work

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to call an API with fetch from React Native App but it doesn't log the response data (`console.warn('data', data)`) for some reason. It prints the 'call to getArtists' log but then nothing happens.

```
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

function getArtists(){
  console.log('call to getArtists')
  return fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.warn('data', data)
    })
}
```

Code is available here: https://snack.expo.io/rkzea2Zlm at components/api-client.js

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to return `data` too

Comment: I noticed using `URL = 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json'` makes the request works. But others doesnt

Comment: I noticed if a print `responseJSON` instead of `data` it works, but I dont understand. The real API I need (LastFM) doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in your "api_client.js", put a return inside like the code bellow.

```
function getArtists(){
  console.log('call to getArtists')
  return fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return data
    })
}
```

In your App.js just do that inside componentWillMount.

```
componentDidMount(){
    getArtists()
      .then(data => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
      });
  }
```

Comment: You have a wrong "then" in your fetch, just do like this code.
function getArtists(){
  console.log('call to getArtists')
  return fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {return data})
}

Comment: Works after remove the last then in getArtists() method inside api_client.js.
I test with alert(JSON.stringify(data)) in componentWillMount.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, seems working. But I dont understand why `console.log(data)` doesnt print the information but `alert` does it. Maybe related to snack (?)

Comment: Problably it's not working with two parameters (Ex.: console.log("teste", data)). If you insert only one parameter will work.